# Pjax Reload Not Work with external Filter

Tags: jquery, gridview, yii2, pjax

Look at the first image.
[image]

that is first condition before i do anything. Now look at second image below:
[image]

When i click on "Direktori Soal" at righ side, the filter for kartik gridview (side left) it is work, because its change the address bar. But when i click the sub of "Pendidikan Agama Islam", there is nothing happen (look at picture below), that is not change the address bar and nothing happen to grid view:
[image]

Anyone ever did too?
help me please..
thanks.